# Reading Polynomial From File in C++?

Tags: c++, file, polynomials

I am trying to read two polynomials from a text file in my c++ program and i have written the following code, my issue is that its *only reading the first one* and the second one is coming out as all zeroes? 
Also im thinking its probably because idk how to stop reading the first poly because apparently you cannot write:
***while(f!='=')***
 anyways heres the code:

```
....
int main()
{
    poly *p1,*p2;
    p1=NULL;
    p2=NULL;
    fstream f;                                               //error: only reading first polynomial
    f.open("input1.txt");
//  string x1="4X7-2X6-1X3+4X2+3X0=0";                  //these are the polynomials im trying to read
//  string x2="2X6+3X2-2X0=0";
    int c,e; 
    char b;
    int x,i=0;
    cout<<"Number of terms of poly 1: ";
    cin>>x;
    while(i<x)
    {
        f>>c>>b>>e;
        cout<<c<<b<<e;
        p1=p1->create(p1,c,b,e);
        i++;
    }
    p1->display(p1);
    cout<<"\nNumber of terms of poly 2: ";
    cin>>x;
    i=0;
    while(i<x)
    {
        f<<endl;
        f>>c>>b>>e;
        cout<<c<<b<<e;
        p2=p2->create(p2,c,b,e);
        i++;
    }
    p1->display(p2);
    poly *p3;
    cout<<"\nThe addition of polynomials is:";
    p3=p3->polyaddition(p1,p2);
    p3->display(p3);
}
```

i wanted to read the polynomials without asking the number of elements on console. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: recommendation: read the full line and use regular expressions to parse

Comment: Test the input stream to ensure that the reads succeeded. Always validate the IO before proceeding to use the results.

Comment: `p1->create(p1,c,b,e)` looks unusual. An object passing itself into one of its own methods should set off alarm bells because an object always knows itself. An object with a create method that is a non-`static` member should set off alarm bells because a create method called on an existing instance isn't creating anything. It might be configuring, but not creating. I think constructing a [mcve] will help you clear out some of the noise and focus on what the problem really is.

Comment: There are a lot of errors in your code.  For example, you're writing `std::endl` to the `fstream`.  You aren't checking any of the input for errors (e.g. "2X6+aX5").  You aren't storing the signs of the terms.  What happens when you read two terms with the same degree?  Maybe first try to figure out what all the possible inputs are and handle them without an error?  If you can handle two terms of the same degree in one polynomial, you should be able to handle adding two polynomials pretty easily.

Answer (score 1):

Most important thing to do: **Write a function** which reads just one monomial component - the next one on the input. Then invoke it repeatedly until you get to the end of the line.

Of course, before *implementing* the function, take the time to carefully consider what the *signature* of that function needs to be; and how a polynomial should be represented, when you don't know its degree in advance.

Notes:

- You absolutely must take care to check for errors, like @user4581301 suggests - so that you don't end up in an infinite loop if the reading fails, or if you hit the end of the line in the middle of a supposed monomial etc.
- Using this function, you'll get the added bonus of avoiding some of the code duplication you have now in reading the two polynomials. To avoid all of it, write a second function which reads an entire single polynomial.